# Move price tag from left to right

Tags: tags, price

can you please give me the right CSS snippet to move these price tags from left to right? I am very insecure with this positioning and don’t want to produce crippled code so it would be great to get some help here.

https://prnt.sc/1x10vpj

I suppose it is thie, but not 100% sure:

````
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    padding: 3px 11px;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
}```

Thanks and regards!
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit of an incomplete question. Would be good to see where the element s sit in relation to other elelements and also associated CSS.

But looks like it is as simple as changing left, to right in your CSS.

Comment: .brk-wc-image .brk-wc-price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    padding: 3px 11px;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
}

Comment: Just tried exchanging 'left' for 'right'-> didn't work

Comment: I get this then: https://prnt.sc/1x90aop

Comment: If that's the case then you will need to post the full code (html and CSS). Need to know what styles are applied to each of the parent elements.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking me here. It is the right code, I mean it DOES do something when edited. I just need the right commands...

Comment: The two basic things to check (sure there are more) when working with absolute positioning, are: (1) is parent element set to position relative or absolute (this provides anchor point for positioning of child elements) (2) that the parent element occupies enough space to allow positioning within (I.e. if you set right:10px and the parent is only 50px wide, then it will have little effect).

Comment: So I recommend checking that the parent occupies (eg width:100%) the column it sits in. If you had provided more information or code in the question, people could have helped further.